# SUMIFS returning only first instance of criteria, how can I fix it?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make a cell show the sum of values meeting the criteria of a date being between one of two dates (aka a range)

for some reason however, the cell is not giving me a correct sum, but instead only reporting the sum of the first instances of each date in the criteria range.

Example:

```
=SUMIFS(G:G,H:H,">="&B4,H:H,"<="&C4)
```

KEY:

B4 = begin date

C4 = end date

G:G = sum range

H:H = criteria range

when I manually sum up the total of the values which match the criteria, I can see it is not adding some of these to the sum. What am I doing wrong? and is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: The concept of the formula looks solid and testing it gives desired functionality. Perhaps take a look at the source data, ensure the dates are all correctly formatted as dates (use text to columns to convert) and that the sum range are formatted as numbers not text (text to columns again)

Comment: Thank you I will try this and report back.

Comment: Thank you, this appears to have worked!